# Execute cat command to overwrite file

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to execute the cat command from my C# code, but I am running into problems.

So, this is just a very simple test, but I end up with the error:

**Error: cat: '>': No such file or directory**

Now... both source and target files actually exist.. and same result if target file does not exist.

If I open a console on my Raspberry Pi, it executes just fine. Any help is much appreciated.

My code:

```
        var srcFile = "/home/pi/tm-satellite/Helpers/wpa_supplicant.conf";
        var outFile = "/home/pi/tm-satellite/network-test.txt";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        var info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        info.FileName = "/bin/bash";
        info.Arguments = $"-c 'cat {srcFile} > {outFile}'";

        info.UseShellExecute = false;
        info.CreateNoWindow = true;

        info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        info.RedirectStandardError = true;

        var p = Process.Start(info);

        //* Read the output (or the error)
        sb.AppendLine($"Args: {info.Arguments}");
        sb.AppendLine($"Output: {p!.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()}");
        sb.AppendLine($"Error: {p!.StandardError.ReadToEnd()}");
        
        p!.WaitForExit();

        return $"Overwrite system file {path}: {p.ExitCode}{Environment.NewLine}{sb}";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're passing the `cat` program the `>` argument.

`>` only makes sense in `bash` or `sh` process where it tells to the interpreter that `stdout` outputs should be dumped into `file`. It's not a valid argument for `cat`.

To get around this, invoke your `cat` process within your shell:

```sh
sh -c 'cat file1 > file2'
```

In C#

```cs
var srcFile = "/home/pi/tm-satellite/Helpers/wpa_supplicant.conf"
var outFile = "/home/pi/tm-satellite/network-test.txt"
var info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.FileName = "sh";
info.Arguments = $"-c 'cat {srcFile} > {outFile}'";
```

Alternatively you can use C#'s `File` utilities to read the first file and write its contents into the second as it might be faster due to less I/O operations.

---

I've fixed my sample. Use double quotes instead of single quotes:

```cs
var srcFile = "~/bad";
var outFile = "~/good";
                
var pInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
  FileName = "sh",
  Arguments = $"-c \"cat {srcFile} > {outFile}\""
};

var process = Process.Start(pInfo);
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: OK.. I will test this shortly... I need to maintain this way of doing it, because I need to update a system file eventually.. thus needing to use sudo...

Comment: Return code 2, source file reports Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Comment: You have probably forgotten to add the closing '

Comment: Nope...copy and paste..  :-)

Comment: info.FileName = "sh";
info.Arguments = $"-c 'cat {srcFile} > {outFile}'";

Comment: Unfortunately.. same problem.. works fine in a console.. but not from code. I have verified that the arguments are correct and strings are terminated correctly.. very odd

Comment: Dang it. What if you replace `sh` with `/bin/bash`?

Comment: Error: /home/pi/tm-satellite/Helpers/wpa_supplicant.conf: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching '"

Comment: could you update your code to the most recent thing?

Comment: Done.. also.. the source file was utf-8 BOM... tested with removing the BOM.. but no change

Comment: I could try it out today and it's because we should use double quotes instead of single quotes when doing `sh -c "command"`

Comment: so, if I need to prefix it with sudo, I guess that will be filename and then move sh to parameter? --- the answer is yes.. works like a charm.